# azure machine cannot joined domain

Tags: azure

dears I just bought a domain from Name cheap and I am using Azure VM Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, now I want to join my windows server on my domain to be as domain controller.
I add my IP address into the domain page, how I can join azure VM to the domain?

Answer (score 0):

For joining the azure domain you need to configure S2S VPN (Site-to-Site VPN) between Azure and the domain and you need to configure your DNS manually to make sure that VM uses domain controller as its DNS server.

1. Here is the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal) to configure Site-to-Site VPN. you can create a new VNET or you can use the existing one if you have any. If you create a new VNET, you may need to re-create VM.
2. From here you can configure the DNS server manually.

[image]

And you can check this [documentation](https://superuser.com/questions/1115047/how-to-join-azure-vm-to-domain) for complete information